# Publishing content to different websites

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content, search-results

I'm running a real estate website and need to publish my every content to different property listing websites through XML feed. Now my question is will Google consider this as duplicate content ? if so how should I fix this ?

Comment: You have different websites which will use content of a feed from another website, right? Please explain more precisely how it will be done.

Comment: @Zistoloen through xml feed every one hour they fetch our content and published in their website(actually we have to pay to list our properties in their [website](http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/home). Please let me know if you have any doubt

Answer (score 1):

In relation to comments under your question, it depends on how your content from tour feed is displayed and which content you put in this feed.

If these websites use content from your feed and just put it in a page with a very little content, it can generate duplicate content issues.

If you considered the deal with these websites valuable, you need to protect your site at least. For this, try to provide a different text between your pages content and content from your feed. In that case, your site is safe regarding duplicate content (even if it's not necessarily the case for websites which display content from your feed). To be safe about duplicate content for these websites, a good idea is to add some text to the content gotten from your feed.